# The getter 'labelLarge' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'

Tags: flutter, flutter-material

can you please help me with this issue in flutter when running my application I'm getting this
error message:
/C:/Users/admin/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/chewie_audio-1.4.0/lib/src/material_controls.dart:82:51: Error: The getter 'labelLarge' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'.

- 'TextTheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/text_theme.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_theme.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'labelLarge'.
  final iconColor = Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelLarge!.color;

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNyB8.png)

I tried downloading the sdk commandline latest but it still won't work for me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `chewie_audio` package is using the `labelLarge` from the `TextTheme` class, which is the replacement for `caption` that was [deprecated after v3.1.0-0.0.pre](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextTheme-class.html). 
But the `material` library in your Flutter SDK is out updated leading to an error: `The getter 'labelLarge' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'`
My suggestion to solve this issue is to upgrade your Flutter SDK and try again.